# alert under echo function of a scriptm does not work in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

The below coding,  includes two function in this program, one function inserts the dealers into database "insert_dealer" before which the a function checks if the particular dealer has already created an account, to do this, i have used function "check_email".

Now my problem is

```
echo "<script>
alert('Username already exist');
 </script>"
```

under the check_user function **the alert works**, 
after which the dealer is inserted into db, where

```
echo "<script>
 alert('Dealer's profile has been added. Login credentials are sent to their mail id.');
</script>
```

**the alert does not work**

**THE NEW DEALER IS ADDED INTO DB, BUT THE ALERT ALONE IS NOT DISPLAYED.**.

please check the code below and suggest your ideas.

```
<?
include_once('config.php');

function insert_dealer($title, $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $token)
{
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");  
{   $user_query = "INSERT INTO dealer_tbl(title, firstname, lastname, email, phone, password, date_created, time_created) 
          VALUES ('$title','$fname','$lname','$email','$phone',password('$token'), CURDATE(), CURTIME())";
}
$user_result = mysql_query($user_query);
// echo $user_query;
if (!$user_result) 
{
    die('Error on query: ' . mysql_error());

}
else    
{   
    echo "<script>
    alert('Dealer's profile has been added. Login credentials are sent to their mail id.');
    window.location = './dealer_portal.php'</script>";
    /*header('Location: dealer_portal.php?status=1&uname='.$email.'&pwd='.$token);*/

}   
}

function check_email($title, $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $token)
{
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");  
{   $dealer_query = "SELECT * FROM `dealer_tbl` WHERE `email` = '". $email ."'";
}
$result = mysql_query($dealer_query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
// echo $user_query;
if ($num_rows > 0) 
{
    echo "<script>
    alert('Username already exist');
    window.location = './dealer_portal.php'</script>";

    return 0;
}else{
insert_dealer($title, $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $token);
return 1;

}   
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question itself but [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). This can save you quite some time eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes are placing problem, try something like this:

```
echo "<script>
    alert('Dealer\'s profile has been added. Login credentials are sent to their mail id.');
    </script>";
```

else you need to concatenate your strings & variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JavaScript error for the case where the alert does not work. The single quote in your text needs to be escaped, or your string should be surrounded by double quotes.

```
echo "<script>
alert('Dealer\'s profile has been added. Login credentials are sent to their mail id.');
window.location = './dealer_portal.php'</script>";
```